# How to set User-Agent (prefix) for every upload request to S3 from Amazon EMR application

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr

AWS has requested that the product I'm working on identifies requests that it makes to our users' S3 resources on their behalf so they can assess its impact.

To accomplish this, we have to set the User-Agent header for every upload request done against a S3 bucket from an EMR application. I'm wondering how this can be achieved?

Hadoop's doc mentions the `fs.s3a.user.agent.prefix` property ([core-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml)). However, the protocol `s3a` seems to be deprecated  ([Work with Storage and File Systems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html)), so I'm not sure if this property will work.

To give a bit of more context what I need to do, with AWS Java SDK, it is possible to set the User-Agent header's prefix, for example:

```java
AWSCredentials credentials;
ClientConfiguration conf = new ClientConfiguration()
    .withUserAgentPrefix("APN/1.0 PARTNER/1.0 PRODUCT/1.0");
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, conf);
```

Then, every request's User-Agent http header will has a value similar to: `APN/1.0 PARTNER/1.0 PRODUCT/1.0, aws-sdk-java/1.11.234 Linux/4.15.0-58-generic Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.201-b09 java/1.8.0_201`. I need to achieve something similar when uploading files from an EMR application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was to include a `awssdk_config_default.json` file inside the JAR submitted to EMR job. This file it used by AWS SDK to allow developers to override some custom settings.

I've added this json file within the JAR submitted to EMR with this content:

```
{
  "userAgentTemplate": "APN/1.0 PARTNER/1.0 PRODUCT/1.0 aws-sdk-{platform}/{version} {os.name}/{os.version} {java.vm.name}/{java.vm.version} java/{java.version}{language.and.region}{additional.languages} vendor/{java.vendor}"
}
```

**Note**: passing the `fs.s3a.user.agent.prefix` property to EMR job didn't work. AWS EMR uses EMRFS when handling files stored in S3 which uses AWS SDK. I realized it because of an exception thrown in AWS EMR that I see sometimes, part of its stack trace was:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.files.TemporaryDirectoriesGenerator.createAndTrack(TemporaryDirectoriesGenerator.java:144)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.files.TemporaryDirectoriesGenerator.createTemporaryDirectories(TemporaryDirectoriesGenerator.java:93)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.create(S3NativeFileSystem.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:932)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:825)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.create(EmrFileSystem.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:135)
```

I'm posting the answer here to future references. Some interests links:

- The class in AWS SDK that uses this configuration file: [InternalConfig.java](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/internal/config/InternalConfig.java)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31173739/1070393
- [EMRFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-fs.html)

Answer (score 0):

S3A is *not* deprecated in ASF hadoop; I will argue that it is now ahead of what EMR's own connector will do. If you are using EMR you may be able to use it, otherwise you get to work with what they implement.

FWIW in S3A we're looking at what it'd take to actually dynamically change the header for a specific query, so you go beyond specific users to specific hive/spark queries in shared clusters. Be fairly complex to do this though as you need to do it on a per request setting.

Comment: Hi @steve-loughran thanks for the answer but it did not work. The property `fs.s3a.user.agent.prefix` was not used by EMR to set the User-Agent when uploading files to S3. Finally I got it to work by including the `awssdk_config_default.json` file inside the JAR submitted to EMR